# Pre processing keras dataset using keras tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to do some pre processing using the keras tokenizer on data I read using the following code:

```
 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x:
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x).prefetch(params.num_parallel_readers),
                                     cycle_length=params.num_parallel_readers,
                                     block_length=1)
        dataset = dataset.map(_parse_example, num_parallel_calls = params.num_parallel_calls)
```

Now that I have the parsed example (output of _parse_example map function) I want to do some pre-processing on the text using `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` method `texts_to_sequences`.
However, texts_to_sequences expects an input of python strings and I get Tensors in the parsed_example.

I can work around it by using `py_func` to wrap my code (see **'emb': tf.py_func..** in the code below), but then I will not be able to serialize my model (according to the `py_func` documentation).

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda features, labels: 
                              ({'window': features['window'],
                                'winSize': features['winSize'],
                                'LandingPage': features['LandingPage'],
                                'emb': tf.py_func(getEmb, [features['window']], tf.int32)},
                                tf.one_hot(labels, hparams.numClasses) ))
```

Looking for a way to do that (or a link to some similar example)

Comment: I was thinking of working around the py_func issue, by using the from_generator method of dataset (in the generator method I planned to read each time some data from the input files and perform the transformation to an indices matrix inside the generator method). However when I tried to run with the from_genrator method I got a warning that  "py_func (from tensorflow.python.ops.script_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.". So, my understanding is that from_generator uses py_func under the hood and therefore this will not work around my issue - am I right?

Comment: Old question, but have you gotten anywhere? I am not sure I understand what you are asking.